# Pointfree style programming in haskell

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I have this function

```
rulesApply :: [PhrasePair] -> Phrase ->  Phrase

rulesApply pp = try (transformationsApply "*" reflect  pp )
```

I want to learn how to make it pointfree.

```
try :: (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> a
try f x = maybe x id (f x)
transformationsApply :: Eq a => a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> ([([a], [a])] -> ([a] -> Maybe [a]))
transformationsApply wc f pfPair list = foldr1 orElse (map (transformationApply wc f list) pfPair)


 rulesApply pp = try (transformationsApply "*" reflect  pp )
```

`(transformationsApply "*" reflect ) pp` has type `Eq a => ([([a], [a])] -> ([a] -> Maybe [a]))`

We see that

```
try :: (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> a
```

so try takes a function `(a -> Maybe a)` as argument. and we see that return type of `(transformationsApply "*" reflect ) pp` is `([a] -> Maybe [a]))` so we should be able to write.

```
rulesApply pp = try . (transformationsApply "*" reflect) pp
```

but this gives compilation error.

Comment: As a tip, you can do `cabal install pointfree`, which will install a command line tool which can take a function and convert it to as close to pointfree as possible.

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you have something that looks like

```
\x -> f (g x)
```

you can turn it into

```
f . g
```

In this case, you have

```
s          x  = f   (g                                 x  )
rulesApply pp = try (transformationsApply "*" reflect  pp )
```

which can be transformed (by moving the argument to the other side of the equation) into

```
s          = \x  -> f   (g                                 x  )
rulesApply = \pp -> try (transformationsApply "*" reflect  pp )
```

which in turn is, according to our rule,

```
s          = f   . g
rulesApply = try . transformationsApply "*" reflect
```

Answer (score 7):

It's relatively easy to remove the points, but you should move step by step.

```
rulesApply pp =  try ( transformationsApply "*" reflect  pp)

=== [partial application]

rulesApply pp =  try ((transformationsApply "*" reflect) pp)

=== [definition of (.)]

rulesApply pp = (try . transformationsApply "*" reflect) pp

=== [eta reduction]

rulesApply    =  try . transformationsApply "*" reflect
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight-forward actually:

```
rulesApply :: [PhrasePair] -> Phrase ->  Phrase
rulesApply = try . transformationsApply "*" reflect
```

Point-free programming is not just about aesthetics. It's about approaching the problem on a higher level: instead of operating on variables of functions, you operate on functions themselves, thus eliminating a whole problem area.

Let's analyze the signature of the `(.)` operator.

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

I intentionally put the braces around `a -> c` to make it clear that it takes two functions to produce another function. In that respect it's not much different from any operator on primitive values, e.g.:

```
(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

Now, don't get obsessed about it and don't expect it to fit any problem on your path. It's just another tool in your pocket, which should be used appropriately. 
It's most common usage is in avoidance of redundant lambdas. Here are some examples:

```
putStrLn . (++ "!") == \a -> putStrLn (a ++ "!")

void . return == \a -> return a >> return ()
```

The second example is basically an equivalent of `const (return ()) == \a -> return ()`, but I just prefer it for aesthetic reasons. I think, compiler optimizes this stuff anyway.